# How to manage and sort integers from a loop in java

Tags: java, string, multidimensional-array, arraylist, hashmap

So I have a loop which will compare two lines of code depending on how many words match, the output of each loop is a percentage of how many words match.
I need to store all the percentages and the according responses so that the highest percentage when all the lines are compared the according response is printed out.

So far I have tried multi-dimensional arrays which doesn't work with strings and doubles I then went on to hashmaps which I couldn't get to work correctly.

What is the preferred way to go about this and can you give examples if possible?

Comment: Could you provide any sample code for what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly:

- create an Object with 2 fields: percentage (int/float) and responses (String)
- for each result create a new instance of that Object and store it in an [java.util.ArrayList](http://javarevisited.blogspot.be/2011/05/example-of-arraylist-in-java-tutorial.html)
- use [Collections.sort](http://blog.vogella.com/2009/08/04/collections-sort-java/) and have your object implement Comparable (where you can simply compare the percentages I guess)

Answer (score 0):

Use a `TreeMap`. Here it is assumed that your percentages are `double`:

```
final TreeMap<Double, String> map = new TreeMap<>();

for (final String lineOfCode: allLinesOfCode())
    map.put(calculatePercentage(lineOfCode), lineOfCode);
```

Then, iterate *in reverse* (the key here is the call to `.descendingMap()`) in order to obtain from highest to lowest:

```
for (final Map.Entry<> entry: map.descendingMap().entrySet())
    // percentage in entry.getKey(), line in entry.getValue()
```

If you only need the last entry (highest percentage):

```
final Map.Entry<> entry = map.lastEntry();
// same as in interation for percentage and line
```

(note: coded for Java 7)

Comment: so I have got to the point where I have a sorted TreeMap and I want to use "final Entry<String, Integer> lastEntry = sorted_map.lastEntry();" but I get the error "cannot find symbol symbol: class Entry" any help?

Comment: Use `Map.Entry` as I wrote; else add an `import static` for `java.util.Map.Entry`.

Comment: using map.Entry didn't work, I fixed by adding the import which is strange considering I already had util imported, thank you for helping

Comment: `**Map**.Entry`. Note the capital M.

Comment: yes neither worked at the time but both work now and I don't see any difference between them.